# Inbox message in app shows HTML encoded characters

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, global-inbox

I can't remember if is has always been like this, but the recent update seems to break the encoding of messages in the inbox in the iOS app:

> [image: Inbox]

This happens in the achievements box too:

> [image: Achievements]

Can this be fixed please?

Comment: Is this with the latest beta?

Comment: Yes. Just downloaded it. It said to test thoroughly, right? ;)

Comment: Patrick, would you mind clarifying the exact version? I have beta 1.3.2.219, and generally get notified of each new version. Have I missed one, or is that what you're using? Thanks!

Comment: This is happening with achievements too. 1.3.2.223

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in build 1.3.2.224.  I've been reworking the way we make calls to the [SE API](https://api.stackexchange.com/).  Before, we were using safe filters everywhere.  These filters are designed to be web app friendly so you can basically stick any string from the API into a webpage without fear of embedding unsafe HTML.

Since we don't really need that, it was mucking up our core library, and it generally causes more trouble than its worth, I switched to using unsafe strings everywhere.  That is, everywhere that doesn't have strings that are "unchanged with unsafe filters", things that truly do contain HTML.  Looking at the documentation for [`inbox_item.body`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/inbox-item) it is one of those places. (Who knew? Maybe there's links in there sometime.)

Anyway, my solution was to add a new type to our next-gen bindings, `SEAPIHTMLString` which is just a wrapper around strings that are documented as "unchanged with unsafe filters".  Here I'll not just be decoding entities like before but also ripping out any tags that may appear.  In the future I may even render the HTML if I figure out why its there.

*This also means that I ported inbox/achievements screens to use some new underlying code, so more chances for breakage.*