# Some HTML tags not being rendered in the iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, flag-dialog

I recently tried to flag a question for moderator attention, and noticed that the guide text saying "Be specific and detailed!" is wrapped inside two not evaluated `<i>` HTML tags for the italic style (which is therefore not rendered).

Here's a screenshot from my phone:

> [image: screenshot]
>
> <sup>(from the StackOverflow site)</sup>

---

Additional details: I'm using an iPhone 4S running iOS 7.1.2 with the Stack Exchange app <strike>v1.4.0</strike> v1.3.2.

Comment: On what site is that? The wording is different than mine. Maybe a site-specific issue.

Comment: I'll add that to the question

Comment: @Pat the bug is with the flag dialog, not flags or flagging process itself. (so if going that extra mile, at least make it as accurate mile as possible :))

Comment: Indeed, I was looking for that one but missed it somehow @Sha

Comment: Can you double check your version in Menu -> About?  v1.4.0 dropped support for iOS7 so I would expect you to have 1.3.2.1, which had this bug.

Comment: @BrianNickel Thank you for making me notice this, I was looking on the AppStore page of the app, but not on my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't reproduce it on the latest beta. It seems to be fixed already. Recently there were some other bug reports related to the replacing of special characters on notifications and others, so probably it is solved already.

> [image: Screen shot]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: By the way, that is on version 1.4.0.239.

Comment: See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264282/245360) for my original bug report. That one was fixed on 1.3.2.224. Not sure why your 1.4 fails.

Comment: You may be right

Comment: Note that I also see the same issue

Comment: What device and version @Braiam? Are you using the beta?

Comment: Mmm, I remember I saw it somewhere... iPhone 4s, 1.4.0, no.

Comment: My device is mentioned in the last comment.

Comment: Ah, that is exactly the setup of OP. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually running **v1.3.2** instead of v1.4.0 (latest) because of my iOS version (7.1.2), so the bug has actually been fixed, but I didn't notice it on my device.

---

I'm a bit sad for the iOS 7 support drop, but that's a common upgrade side effect... got to deal with it.